# What's the difference between biconditional iff and logical equivalence?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am confused about the difference between ↔ (biconditional iff) and ≡ (logical equivalence). For instance, p→q can be rewritten as ∼p∨q. Would it be correct to say p→q↔∼p∨q or p→q≡∼p∨q?

Secondly, is ⇔ another symbol for ≡?

Finally, what's the difference between → and ⇒?

Comment: You should look in that book to see what the symbols mean.  For example, it could be that $\rightarrow$ combines two wffs into a new wff, while $\Rightarrow$ is a relation between wffs.

Comment: The issue is not with the *symbols* but with the *concepts*. We have a *connective*: the [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) that can produce a "complex" sentence (or formula) from simpler ones: $p \leftrightarrow q$.

Comment: And we have the relation of [logical (or semantical) equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) between formulas. Logical equivalence is different from the biconditional, although the two concepts are closely related; in a nutshell: $p \leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology iff $p$ is logically equivalent to $q$.

Comment: See also this answer on SE Philosophy: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/65024/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-equivalence-and-material-equivalence

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#History_of_notations seems to suggest they could mean the same across time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference inbetween $\leftrightarrow$, $\iff$, and $\equiv$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926367/what-is-the-difference-inbetween-leftrightarrow-iff-and-equiv)

Answer (score 19):

In short, $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is statement that could be either true or false.  $P \equiv Q$ means that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is always a true biconditional (so, $P$ and $Q$ have the same truth value no matter what).

So, one could say that $\neg (P \vee Q) \equiv \neg P \wedge \neg Q$ (DeMorgan's) but you typically wouldn't write $\neg (P \vee Q) \leftrightarrow (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$.

The arrow $\Rightarrow$ usually is slang for "implies" but different people use it differently.  The arrow $\Leftrightarrow$ is usually treated the same way as $\leftrightarrow$.

Comment: I found it's clearer to mention the **components** in logical equivalence: $\phi \equiv \psi$ means for that every truth assignment applied to **the components of** $\phi$ and $\psi$, the resulting truth values of $\phi$ and $\psi$ are identical.

Answer (score 8):

In case you can use a somewhat philosophical explanation: $\leftrightarrow$ is a logical operator within statements, while $\equiv$ serves to state an equivalence *between* statements and thus may be thought of as meta-logical.

As Randall explained, $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is a statement $-$ *one* statement and a *logical* statement. The $\leftrightarrow$ will cause it to be true under certain truth value distributions for $P$ and $Q$. The same applies to $\neg(P \vee Q) \leftrightarrow (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$.

For $\neg(P \vee Q) \equiv (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$ however, you compare two truth tables, the one of $\neg(P \vee Q)$ and $(\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$, *two* distinct statements. If and only if both are true exclusively for the same truth value distributions, the equivalence applies and so the *meta-logical* statement $\neg(P \vee Q) \equiv (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$ is true.

Comment: This is what I've expected to hear actually. So thank you for the insight!

Comment: A fancy way to put this is to say that $\leftrightarrow$ appears in object-language whereas $\equiv$ appears in meta-language

Comment: Do you mean that $\ldots≡\ldots$ is the same as $\forall \ldots ↔\ldots$?

Answer (score 6):

Consider this analogy. You wouldn't say the following:

> Prove that 3 + 5.

You might instead say this:

> Prove that 3 = 5.

---

Similarly, following doesn't make sense:

> Prove that $p \leftrightarrow q$.

Instead one of these would be correct:

> Prove that $p \leftrightarrow q$ is always true.
>   or
>   Prove that $p \equiv q$.