# is \iff the same as \equiv? When to use which?

Tags: logic

Is there a difference between using $\iff$(\iff) and $\equiv$ (\equiv)?

When should I use one or the other?

Comment: What about $\leftrightarrow$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between biconditional iff and logical equivalence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432462/whats-the-difference-between-biconditional-iff-and-logical-equivalence)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a strict rule (or even all that great of a consensus) as to what symbol to use where and when.  The most important thing is that you understand the  difference between a *logic symbol* and a *meta-logic* symbol:

The *material biconditional* is a truth-function that takes two logic expressions and combines them into a new one.  As such, it is *part of* a logic statement. You often see $P \leftrightarrow Q$, but some books use $P \equiv Q$, and some use $P \Leftrightarrow Q$

On the other hand, *logical equivalence* is a statement *about* two logic statements, namely that they have the same truth-conditions. We know, for example, that the logic statement $\neg (P \lor Q)$ is logically equivalent to $\neg P \land \neg Q$.  We can write a symbol between them to say this *about* them, but as such we don't get a new logic statement, but rather a *meta-logical* statement. For this, I can't recall ever having seen the $\leftrightarrow$ used, but you'll see both $\neg (P \lor Q) \equiv \neg P \land \neg Q$ and $\neg (P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land \neg Q$. I've also seen $\neg (P \lor Q) :: \neg P \land \neg Q$

Anyway, context should make it clear what is meant by which symbol, and which symbol you are therefore supposed to use.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the definition from Rosen's `Discrete Mathematics and its Applications`.

> **Definition:**
>
> The compound propositions $p$ and $q$ are called logically equivalent if $p \iff q$ is a tautology. The notation $p \equiv q$ denotes that $p$ and $q$ are logically equivalent.

That is, the symbol $\equiv$ is **not a logical connective**, and $p \equiv  q$ is not a compound proposition **but rather is the statement that $p \iff q$ is a tautology.**

Comment: Please do not recommend Rosen's textbook, as it is full of conceptual errors and imprecision. This is well known to many mathematicians but not to most students.