# What are the differences between logical equivalence and "if and only if"?

Tags: logic

I am confused. If $q,p$ are logically equivalent ($q\equiv p$) it means that they both have exactly the same truth values.

The connector "if and only if", $q\iff p$ is a true statement when both $q$ and $p$ have the same truth value.

1. So why is $\equiv$ and $\iff$ used to denote the same thing?
2. Second question, what is the difference between a logical symbol and a meta-logical symbol?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is \iff the same as \equiv? When to use which?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506497/is-iff-the-same-as-equiv-when-to-use-which)

Comment: The natural language "if and only if" may mean both the sentential connective [Logical bi-conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) as well as the relation of [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence): two notions that are different but strictly linked.

Comment: No, it does not. @soupless

Comment: "The **formula** q⟺p is a true statement when both q and p have the same truth value." Correct, but the formula **does not** asserts that they have, while the "meta" expression  "$\phi$ and $\psi$ are logical equiv" instead asserts it.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649394/difference-between-biconditional-and-logical-equivalence) with further link and see the post [Distinction between language and metalanguage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159383/is-the-distinction-between-language-and-metalanguage-strictly-parallel-the-disti).

Comment: I agree that $q \iff p$ is not necessarily true. So if I use $\equiv$ I assert that both $q,p$ have the same truth value and if I use $\iff$ I don't mean it. Am I right? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Exactly. If you write formula $\lnot p$ what is its truth-value? Answer: it depends.