# What is the difference between p ↔ q and p ≡ q?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, notation

Im currently new to understanding the propositional logic and I am really confused on the difference between p ↔ q and p ≡ q.

Comment: See [List of logic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols): usually, none.

Comment: Usually they mean the same thing, and each book will use one or the other, not both.  But if your book uses both, you'll need to find out what that particular book means by it.  There might be a “glossary of symbols” at the front or the back that may help.

Comment: In some contexts, $\leftrightarrow$ is used for the propositional conncetive [bi-conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) while $\equiv$ is used for [logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) (both usually read: **iff**).

Comment: See the similar post: [what's-the-difference-between-biconditional-iff-and-logical-equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432462/whats-the-difference-between-biconditional-iff-and-logical-equivalence)